# Overlay View with Subview, don't know calling VC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewcontroller

I need a view (infoView) to be displayed as an overlay on top of another view. As this infoView should be callable from every view of the app(e.g. introView), I'd like the code to be in the infoViews VC and just call its methods when an action at the currentView (introView) happens. I can't use push and pop, as I need to change the background color (infoView) and especially the alpha of the calling view (introView), so right now I do it with insertSubview.

My Code by now:
introVC .h

```
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender;
IBOutlet InfoVC *infoScreenVC;
```

introVC .m

```
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender {
    [infoScreenVC openInfoMethod];}
```

infoVC .h

```
- (IBAction) closeInfoPressed;
- (void) openInfoMethod;
- (void) closeInfoMethod;
```

infoVC .m

```
- (IBAction) closeInfoPressed {
    [self closeInfoPressed];}

- (void) closeInfoMethod {
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.xx.view setAlpha:1.0f];}

- (void) openInfoMethod {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.xx.view setAlpha:0.2f];
[((MyAppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window 
    insertSubview: self.infoScreenVC.view aboveSubview: self.xx.view];}
```

When I push the button to show the infoView, my NSLogs tell me the method was called, but I can see the Subview wasn't added. I have absolutely no clue what to insert where right now it says xx in my code, as a VC reference from intro doesn't show me the screen. 
If I put that code in introVC an modify it, it does show the infoView, calls the correct method to close, but again can't close (when I'm in introVC). I can't figure out how to tell my app who was the calling VC to get back there.
At some point, when all the code was in introVC I managed to even remove the Subview, but couldn't set the Alpha of introVC back to one.

I do struggle with that since two days.. -.- Or is there maybe an easier solution even?

Thank you very much!

//Edit after sergios answer:
intro.m

```
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender {
introViewController *introVC; 
[infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:];}
```

info.h

```
- (void) openInfoMethod:(introViewController *introVC);
```

info.m

```
- (void) openInfoMethod:(introViewController *introVC) { //error occurs here
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.introVC.view setAlpha:0.2f];
[((MyAppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).window 
insertSubview: self.infoScreenVC.view aboveSubview: self.introVC.view];}
```

and the occurring error says

```
Expected ')' before 'introVC'
```

I'm not sure how to pass the VC reference properly.
Thank you for your help!!

//EDIT Working Code:

As it works now, I'd like to sum things up:
- I give the calling VC (introVC) to openInfoMethod on the Action openInf like `[infoVC openInfoMethod:introVC]`.

- In openInfoMethod I "save" the calling VC in a local variable of type introVC (?) and add the overlay etc.
- When the Action of the infoViewController named closeInfoPressed occurs, it calls infoViewController's method closeInfoMethod like `self closeInfoMethod:introVC`.
- In that method I remove self.view from Superview and set introVC.view's Alpha to 1 like introVC.view setAlpha:1.0f

So the codesnippets are
intro.h

```
IBOutlet InfoscreenViewController *infoScreenVC;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet InfoscreenViewController *infoScreenVC;
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender;
```

intro.m

```
@synthesize infoScreenVC;
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender {
UIViewController *introVC = self;
[infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:introVC];
}
```

info.h:

```
- (void) openInfoMethod:(UIViewController *)rootVC;
- (void) closeInfoMethod:(UIViewController *)callingVC;
```

info.m

```
- (void) closeInfoMethod:(UIViewController *)callingVC;{
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[callingVC.view setAlpha:1.0f];
}

- (IBAction) closeInfoPressed{
[self closeInfoMethod:introVC];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is "figure out how to tell my app who was the calling VC to get back there", why don't you add a parameter to openInfo selector, like here:

info.h

```
- (void) openInfoMethod:(introViewController *)introVC;
```

info.m

```
- (void) openInfoMethod:(introViewController *)introVC {
    <your implementation here>
}
```

would this work for you?

EDIT: your  code from intro.m has got a small problem,

```
- (IBAction) openInf:(id)sender {
    introViewController *introVC; 
    [infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:];
}
```

indeed, you are not initializing your `introVC` variable, so that when you pass it into `-openInfoMethod:` it will have some weird value and cause a crash.

As far as I can grasp from your code, `intro.m` should be the implementation file for your `introViewController`, therefore you can simply call:

```
    [infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:self];
```

but please, before doing this, confirm that `self` is actually your `introViewController`.

Comment: @sergio Thanks for your reply, that sounds like what I need, but I'm not sure how to do that.. Could you be a bit more specific? 

(It seems I can't post code into a comment, please see my edit for the code I have now. Thanks!

Comment: @sergio Thank you! Like this it compiles without any error or warning! But when I run the App it crashes right when I call the method like this: [infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:introVC];, after I made a ref like introViewController *introVC;. Am I calling it wrong (again)?

Comment: @sergio Thanks again! In introViewController.m I have introViewController *introVC = self; [infoScreenVC openInfoMethod:introVC]; but it crashes there. BUt that should be correct, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Nareille: I think so, but you can know that for sure if you put a breakpoint on that call and check the introVC has the right value you expect. After that, I would step into `openInfoMethod:` (or put a breakpoint in its first line), debug step by step and see where and shy it crashes...

Comment: @sergio 
//edit: i had the *introVC with assign-property, with retain it works now. like this I had it a few days ago (before I messed it all up while trying to make it work -.-) so right now the infoView appears, the alpha of introVC is reduced to 0.2 and i can also close infoView (remove the subview), but that's where I stuck now. How to tell the close-Action who the calling view (introVC) was? Thank you!

Comment: @Nareille: I see... well, you could store `introVC` in a local variable in your infoView (this you would do in `openInfoMethod:` and reuse that value in `closeInfoMethod`. I am not sure this is the nicest design, but it should work...

Comment: @sergio I tried, but I probably do something wrong.. In opnenInfoMethod i set something like rootVC = introVC (which was passed when the method was called and RootVC being declared in infoVC.h and synthesized in .m) and than in the close-Action I try to call the closeMethod like [self closeInfoPressed:rootVC] than it crashes. closeInfoPressed is defined as closeInfoPressed:(introViewController *) introVC (Which is definitly not nice, as I need it to be able to get any kind of VC, as every view like introVC should be able to call it)I can't give that rootVC directly into the Action, can I?

Comment: @sergio Could this have any impact on the other Buttons available on introVC? I just realized they won't direct me anywhere anymore. I checked the Actions and Connections, everythings fine, no error, no warning, but unfortunately also nothing to happen. Is it possible this fiddling broke anything or is it impossible, and I simply screwed it up another place?

Comment: @Nareille: I think there was a misunderstanding: your `closeInfoPressed` is the IBAction, so better you don't change its declaration. What I suggested to change was the implementation (not the declaration) of `closeInfoMethod`. If you changed the declarations of your IBAction, you have definitely (unfortunately) messed something up... sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: @sergio Sorry, I confused things.. I ment `closeInfoMethod` is defined as `closeInfoMethod:(introViewController *) introVC` not `closeInfoPressed`. And by writing that, I see that I also mixed it in the real code -.- Now it works!Thanks a thousand, no, a million times! I'll post the final code in my question for others as reference! Thanks so much for your time and patience!

Comment: @sergio Uuuuuhm... :) My I ask one more thing concerning this? I use the setup as in the summary, where everything is referenced to as UIViewController, so I thought it will work for other calling VCs (like introVC), but apparently it won't. For introVC it's still working though. I set up the connections, the code for the other VC is the same in the `openInf`-Action besides of course `UIViewController *tippsVC = self;` but that won't call the method in fact. The infoViewController is added to tippsViewController.h and there are no errors or warnings. Any idea? And sorry to disturb you again..

Comment: @Nareille: I haven't clear exactly what does not work as expected, and in principle there should be no problem in generalizing your design to other kinds of UIViewControllers... maybe you could ask a new question and restate the problem fully? If you are not of this mind, what I would do is set a few breakpoints where you expect your code to be called (say, the actions), and step through from there to inspect things...

Comment: @sergio I'll go through it with breakpoints a few more times, seeing if I can nail it down somewhere and than, if I can't fix it, I'll ask a new question! I just wondered whether this SHOULD work at all. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be ilke this

- (void) openInfoMethod:(introViewController *)introvc  you are passing parameters in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your infoView should be a subclass of UIView and instantiated from any of your view controllers using:

```
InfoView *infoView = [[InfoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX,originY,width,height)];
```

Then you simply add it as a subview of your view controllers view:

```
[self.view addSubView:infoView];
[infoView release]; // It's safe to release it here as your view controller's view is retaining it
```

And when you are done with it, simply call

```
[infoView removeFromSuperview];
```

As an aside, you could create some simple methods inside infoView that include introducing animation when the view is presented or removed. Here's an example for fade in and out which assume you set the alpha to zero initially when you create the view:

```
- (void)fadeIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{self.alpha = 1.0f}];
}
```

And fade out

```
- (void)fadeOut {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{self.alpha = 0f} 
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished){self removeFromSuperView}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! infoView needs to be of UIViewController, as there should also be some buttons, directing to other views. I had a similar approach, adding and removing Subviews inside the calling VC in the beginning, but as more viewControllers had to be added, I had to c&p the actions to every view controller, which doesn't seem such a good idea, as I maybe have to change something in the infoView, and than would have to check every other ViewController..  I'll keep the animation in my mind and definitely add it, as soon as the basic functions work!